# Integrate a design into an ember cli project

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I am just trying to add a design to my ember cli app, I copied all the assets files of my design to the /public folder and imported them in app/index.html but most files give errors in loading.

I thought the web would be full with examples but actually did not find any :) Could anybody recommend a link or a tutorial?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Ember CLI documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/)  on asset compilation. This shows how to reference images in templates and stylesheets.

I don't think you should be referring to them in `index.html` but you may need to do so in the `application.hbs` or `index.hbs` templates.

Styles should be compiled into your `app.css` or `vendor.css` as appropriate. Put your code under the `app/styles/` directory and use an `app.import` statement in your `Brocfile.js` to include framework code.

Comment: thanks surreymagpie for the answer, Yes for images and small pieces of code I got to manage it, but actually I have a design with lot of complicated css and js. Do you mean I must copy the whole template in app/styles/ folder then import all files in Brocfile.js? could you confit this please!

Comment: Why does the complexity of your design make any difference?

The `Brocfile.js` only needs to be edited to specify if you need any library's code, e.g. modernizr, which you won't need to edit yourself. The best place for those assets is under `vendor`. These are concatenated in the order you specify into a file called `vendor.css` which loads before your `app.css`.

If it's code you are responsible for just write or copy it into `app.css` and it will be included automatically by the build process. Without better understanding of what is difficult with your design, it's hard to say more.